# Extract text under specific heading or only the listItems

Tags: c#, aspose.words

I need to extract the text under a specific heading.

word document example:

> ### afbakening
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula >eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis
> natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus
> mus. Donec quam felis,
>
> List item
>
> 1. List item
> 2. List item
> 3. List item
>
> ### Another heading
>
> this is text i do not need to extract

So the text under the heading “afbakening” needs to be extracted.

It would be even better if someone knows how to extract only the list items as strings under that specific heading.

Comment: I don't see a question here

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try to search online how it works when you handle texts and strings, there are many ways to do this. Being specifically sticking to your precise need, you can actually simply search the title of "Afbakening" and set a variable to the maximum length of text (being that the exact position of Another, or just what you want it to be), search then for any instance where you find X + ". List item" (being X an int) and store the List item in a variable fitting your need. There are many possibilities, but since there's no specific use or purpose for your need stated in the question, this answer gets as ambiguous as the question. Still, i recommend you to try out some tecniques, even the Substring function for the strings can help.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can use [DocumentVisitor](https://apireference.aspose.com/words/net/aspose.words/documentvisitor) to extract content from your document. For example see the following code:

```cs
Document doc = new Document(@"C:\temp\in.docx");
MyVisitor visitor = new MyVisitor();
doc.Accept(visitor);
```

```cs
private class MyVisitor : DocumentVisitor
{
    public override VisitorAction VisitParagraphStart(Paragraph paragraph)
    {
        // Detect heading paragraph. Heading 1 style is used for demonstration purposes.
        if (paragraph.ParagraphFormat.StyleIdentifier == StyleIdentifier.Heading1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Heading Started: {0}", paragraph.ToString(SaveFormat.Text).Trim());
        }

        // Detect list items.
        if (paragraph.IsListItem)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", paragraph.ToString(SaveFormat.Text).Trim());
        }

        return VisitorAction.Continue;
    }
}
```